# How to propagate Model changes through ViewModel in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, mvvm, swiftui

I am trying to understand the MVVM pattern in SwiftUI, but I am not understanding exactly how the ViewModel listens to and propagates changes from a Model object.  Many examples, including [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app) from Apple, talk about having a Model inherit from ObservableObject and use that directly in your View.  This makes sense.

But what is the best/recommended way that a ViewModel should observe changes to its underlying Model?

A simple example is a `WidgetView` that displays the `title` of a widget, but the `title` can change in the background from a background network call, for example.

```
class WidgetView: View {
    @ObservedObject var widgetVM = WidgetViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text(widgetVM.title)
    }
}

class WidgetViewModel : ObservableObject {
   var widget: Widget

   var title: String {
      get {
         // Some translation to the title for this particular view
         return widget.title + "!"
      }
   }
}

struct Widget {
    // Some other timer or background process is changing the title
    var title: String
}
```

One rough solution I've explored is having a separate `title` and listening for changes.  So if `Widget` extended `ObservableObject` and `@Published` the `title` field, then the `WidgetViewModel` could do the following:

```
class WidgetViewModel : ObservableObject {
   var widget: Widget

   @Published var title: String = ""
   var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

   init() {
       self.cancellable = widget.$title.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
           .sink(receiveValue: self.updateTitle )
   }

   func updateTitle(_: String) {
       self.title = widget.title + "!"
   }
}
```

Is it recommended/standard for `Widget` to extend `ObservableObject` too?  If so, how does `WidgetViewModel` properly pass notifications of changes through?  It would seem that `WidgetModelView.widget` would need to be both a @Published and an @ObservedObject, but that doesn't seem right.

Anyone have any insight here?

Comment: You don't need `widget` to be `@Published`.  Your `Widget` can publish changes to its `title` through Combine as you have shown or you could use `Notification` or any other method you like.  You don't need `Widget` to conform to `ObservableObject` in order to have a publisher for `title`.  You could expose a `Subject` for `title`

Comment: Assuming I used a different notification mechanism from the Model to the ViewModel (I will research these), is there a way to notify the View without having a Published property that I set (I.e. so that I don’t have to have a separate title field in the ViewModel)?

Comment: No, that is the cost of having both a model and a view model.  Your view model typically has a bunch of glue code to propogate events up/down.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Widget` is struct, so it cannot be `ObservableObject`, instead you can just do the following

```
class WidgetViewModel : ObservableObject {

   var widget: Widget {
     didSet {
        updateTitle(widget)    // << here !!
     }
   }

   @Published var title: String = ""

   func updateTitle(_: String) {
       self.title = widget.title + "!"
   }
}
```

Comment: This won't help if you update `widget.title` eg. from network request (which, I believe, is what the question was about).